# PyDev- Project runs on one computer but same exact project gives "ImportError: No module named" error on another - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pydev, python-import

I am getting acquainted with Python and the pygame library in particular. I'm starting by attempting to make my own 2D RPG through a YouTube tutorial. I backed up my whole project from my work computer to GitHub, but when I clone the repository to my personal computer, my main class doesn't recognize any of my imports even though it works on my other computer.

My file structure:

```
project folder
 |
 ----- main.py
 |
 ----- map_editor.py
 |
 +---- scripts
         |
         ----- globals.py
         |
         ------ UltraColor.py
         |
         ------ textures.py
```

I have added `__init__.py` to all of my folders on my private copy, and that handles the errors pertaining to the imports, but then I get floating method errors for calls to those imports' methods.

My current imports:

```
import pygame, sys, math
from scripts.textures import *
from scripts.UltraColor import *
```

Error I'm receiving:

> ImportError: No module named scripts.textures

I understand that with enough changes and configuration to the code that I could maybe get it to work on that machine but I want to know why it already runs error-free on one machine but not on the other.

Comment: What is the exact command you're running, and what is the current working directory when you run it?

Comment: I am running my main files that contain the game loops in them from the Eclipse with pydev. It's just much faster than typing to the python command line to run it every time. Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: What is your OS? And what was the OS of the original machine.  If you start up python from the command line, can you import the strings mannually?

Comment: I am running win7 on the machine that works and win10 on the one where it doesn't work. I tried the imports from the python shell and they didnt work there either

Comment: Do you use the same Python version on both computers?

Comment: Oh my god I think this is on Python 3 and the home one is on 2.7... Checking now, will verify shortly.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, please add: `import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))` to the start of your script and pass the output. Also, please specify which python version you're using and make sure that your `project folder` is on the project pythonpath (see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try add an `__init__.py` in scripts folder

hope it work

Best regard

Comment: I added `__init__.py` to all the directories which led to other error but I want the same version to work on both machines. If I change it to work on my personal computer then I don't want it to not work on my work computer.